Unable to View "Secrets" Tab in GitHub Settings for SonarQube Integration
I am trying to integrate GitHub with SonarQube, following the official documentation:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions
https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/9.8/devops-platform-integration/github-integration/
So far, I have completed the first two steps:

Created a GitHub App.
Installed the GitHub App in my organization.

However, in the third step, I need to create GitHub secrets. The documentation states that secrets should be stored in the "Secrets" tab under the settings section. Despite having full admin access to the repository, I am unable to view the "Secrets" tab.
Github's setting section
Steps Taken:

Verified that I have full admin access.
Checked multiple documentations, all mentioning the same step to add secrets.
Integrated Jenkins pipeline with SonarQube and working fine.
Using GitHub Enterprise Server 3.12.5

Is there an alternative way to complete the GitHub and SonarQube integration without using the "Secrets" tab? Or is there a specific requirement or setting that I might be missing to make the "Secrets" tab visible?

Please send a screenshot of your Settings

It is attached in the problem statment @DeltaGeorge (alt text- Github's setting section)

It appears that you do not have GitHub Actions enabled on your GitHub Enterprise Server. You should see the following under your repo Settings when Actions are enabled:

I believe that Actions are not enabled by default on the Enterprise Server because Actiins require storage configuration to store workflow logs and artifacts as well as self-hosted runner configuration to run the workflows, something that one gets automatically on GitHub.com.
